# Deep link not working for captive portal

Tags: android, google-chrome, deep-linking

***REPOST***
So im still having problem with android captive portal/chrome with authpuppy.

Once im connected to a wifi, the captive portal will will pop up, showing a custom page and when user clicks on a button on the page, my app will open.

no matter what i did, on clicking the button, the captive portal will show ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME as error. Chrome will show ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED as error.

I had no problem with firefox or normal web browser.

If successfully authenticate, all the above works like charm, but if pending authentication (no internet) then it will not work.

Android as follows:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.mydomain.com"
                android:pathPattern="/a/b/c/" />

            <data
                android:scheme="myapp"
                android:host="www.mydomain.com"
                android:pathPattern="/a/b/c/" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And html as follows:

```
<a href="intent://www.mydomain.com/a/b/c/#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.mypackage;S.browser_fallback_url=http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=blablabla&hl=en;end;";></a>
```

Can someone pls help me out?

Comment: did you find the solution? I encountered the same problem.

Comment: @semih Nope. doesn't seem to find any solution. Decided not to use captive portal afterall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android on Chrome / WebView, you should use an Intent per Google Chrome Documentation

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Example
   intent://@Intent;scheme=abcd://;package=com.abcd.yourapp;S.browser_fallback_url=http://m.abcd.com

Comment: i tried using as above <a href="intent://#Intent;scheme=myscheme;package=mypackage;S.browser_fallback_url=;end">. Given that my app is not in published in store, by clicking, it will navigate to playstore. So do i assume its working? it doesn't launch my app though.

Comment: That was an example, you should replace the scheme/package with what you have in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: thanks for replying. Yeah i know. I replaced all param with mine. But deep link will not work if there's limited to no connectivity, in my case, in a captive portal pening authentication.